# add(...) in List cannot be applied to (...)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working with recyclerview. I got this error *add(...OmborActivty) in List cannot be applied to (...OmborModel)*. In following part I used ***this***: *Recyc_Adapter_Ombor myAdapter = new Recyc_Adapter_Ombor(**this**, lstOmbor);*. Some guys said to use getAcivity() or getContext(). But when I am typing instead of ***this*** the above advised methods I am getting "Cannot resolve method".

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.adapters.Recyc_Adapter_Ombor;
import com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation.models.Ombor_Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OmborActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<OmborActivity> lstOmbor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ombor);


        lstOmbor = new ArrayList<>();
        lstOmbor.add(new Ombor_Model("Zara", "Qizlar uchun shim", "85 ming so'm", R.drawable.img));
        lstOmbor.add(new Ombor_Model("Gucci", "Qizlar uchun triko", "189 ming so'm", R.drawable.img));
        lstOmbor.add(new Ombor_Model("Gucci", "Qizlar uchun ko'ylak", "100 ming so'm", R.drawable.img));
        lstOmbor.add(new Ombor_Model("Versaci", "Qizlar uchun ko'ylak", "120 ming so'm", R.drawable.img));


        RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_ombor);
        Recyc_Adapter_Ombor myAdapter = new Recyc_Adapter_Ombor(this, lstOmbor);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to add an instance of the wrong type to a collection. re-check your code

Comment: List<Ombor_Model> lstOmbor; Change this

Comment: @MayurRaval thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `List<OmborActivity> lstOmbor;` to `List<Ombor_Model> lstOmbor;`